# Should an API be responsible for sending mail?

Tags: php, api, email

I am developing an API for a company. They have multiple projects lined up to interact with the API.

The API will be sent an id of an object to disable. If this is successful the user who's item was disabled should receive an email.

My question is this: should the API be responsible for sending the email or should the API return that the object was disabled and the email address to send the email to?

Many thanks, looking forward to your opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, I'd say it depends. Since the requirement of sending an email is directly in scope of the API and the API doesn't do much else, I don't see why it shouldn't send it. However, I would consider certain levels of configuration.

You could provide a function which simply returns the email address (or use a flag) and one function which does the whole thing (this should be configurable as well, e.g. set smtp server, email body text etc.). If you were to incorporate the email functionality, providing a simple function/method which only does the object manipulation comes cheap.

NB: In any case I'd try to resolve this requirement ambiguity with the company/customer before starting to develop. It could save you development work.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't so much whether an API should send an email in the general case, but whether the system you're developing which disables the object should be responsible for sending emails. This will depend on a number of factors such as:

1. Is it legal that an object is disabled but an email hasn't been sent? With the split responsibility, there's a risk that the other system will fail to send an email? Perhaps the email address was invalid or the mail server is down. Will this inconsistency cause any catastrophic effect? If so, the email should probably be sent by your object disabling system.
2. Are either of the two systems already responsible for sending other emails? If so, perhaps all email sending should be done there.

At the end of the day, both solutions may be "correct" to some degree for different reasons. The only obviously bad design would be to have your system call back to the other system as this would create a circular dependency.